# How can i get the dynamic number of textboxes values from jsp in struts?

Tags: struts-1

I am having number of textboxes, where user will enter comments in indivddual textbox. I need to fetch all the textboxes values and pass it to action class. Please help me to move forward.

This is my jsp code:

```
   <layout:collectionItem  title="Comments">
        <layout:text readonly="true" property="comments"
        ondblclick="javascript:enableText(this);" name="comments"
        layout="false" />
   </layout:collectionItem>
```

This is my action class code:

```
    DynaActionForm dynaForm = (DynaActionForm) form;
    TablesVo tablesVo = new TablesVo();

    tablesVo.setComments((String) dynaForm.get("comments"));
    System.out.println("Comments:>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
                + (String) dynaForm.get("comments"));
```

This is my struts config code:

```
  <form-bean name="projectForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">

  <action-mappings>

  <action path="/Projects" type="com.rntbci.ptm.client.action.PTMManageAction"
            name="projectForm" scope="session" parameter="reqCode">
            <forward name="display_projects" path="tile.ptm.projects" />
            <forward name="display_columns" path="tile.ptm.columns" /> 
  </action>

  </action-mappings>
```

I am struggling to solve this problem for the past four days. 
Please do me a favour.

Comment: So, what you have tried so far?

Comment: I can get first text box value and updated..! But I need to get all textboxes values..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give same `name` attribute to all your textboxes

```
<input type="text" name="comment"/>
<input type="text" name="comment"/>
...
<input type="text" name="comment"/>
```

Now in your action class instead of declaring a string variable declare a List variable

```
private List<String> comment; //with getter/setter
```

You can now iterate over this list to read the comments

```
Iterator<String> it = comment.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
   System.out.println("\n comment: "+it.next());
}
```

Comment: I am not able to get the list of comments from my jsp to my action class...! I am using same name attribute only..!

Comment: Can you show your code. How are you submitting your values? Edit your question to add your jsp and action class code.Also your action mapping

Comment: I need to update all comments to my database. I am having number of textboxes(for comments) which will be displayed dynamically.

Comment: Oh you are using struts1 but you tagged the question struts2. You are reading the `comments` vairable as a string,in your action class. Make it a List of string.I have not worked with struts1 so I exactly dont know the syantax.If you fail after trying I will try to find the struts1 specific solution

Comment: Thanks for ur effort and help and I tried with list too.. but the value coming from my jsp to action class is string not a list thats the problem.